# Get UserName in overridden DBContext SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: authentication, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

This is a Blazor Server App running in render-mode="Server".

I have overridden my DBContext SaveChangesAsync and SaveChanges so that auditing details can be added to each changed record of the database.

Blazor authentication/authorization is accomplished by use of a custom Authentication State provider that uses Blazored.SessionStorage session var "authToken" which contains the Bear token.

```
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ISessionStorageService _localStorageService;

    public CustomAuthStateProvider(ISessionStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        string authToken = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync("authToken");

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
        {
            try
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(authToken), "jwt");
            }
            catch
            {
                await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            }
        }

        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var state = new AuthenticationState(user);

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));

        return state;
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer
            .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

        var claims = keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));

        return claims;
    }
}
```

Overridden SaveChanges() code:

```
       public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var provider = this.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        var authState = await provider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var name = authState.User.Identity.Name;

        SetAudit();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

This code works fine except when GetAuthenicationStateProvider is called from within my DbContext where it abends with -        $exception  {"JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method."}    System.InvalidOperationException

This does not make sense to me as the DbContext is a DAL project called by the Blazor Server app.

Any insights as to why this is happening and how to fix it?